# how to open a URL via browser , in the windows user login?

Tags: windows, cross-browser, command, scheduled-tasks, startup

**My need :**

1. I need a **button/icon** to be inserted in the **red color box** specified area of the **unlock computer window**.
2. If the user click the **button/icon** , I need to open a particular **URL** in the **browser**.

   [image]

Any suggestions and idea's will be welcome.

Hope I will get a better solution here.

Comment: Short answer is: you can't do this as this is highly security-sensitive. Long answer is - for Windows XP - google for "custom gina windows xp"

Comment: Thanks . Give a short answer for the question . So that I can gave my bounty to you .

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't do this as this is highly security-sensitive. If it was easy, any malware could add links to ads for example...

That being said, on Windows XP, you can google for "custom gina windows xp", and it will bring you back articles on how to customize the logon screen, for example: 
[Security Briefs: Customizing GINA, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx) by Keith Brown.